# system time setting using c library function

Tags: c

I can get the system time using struct tm and time(),localtime(),asctime().but i need help about how i can set time of system using c program.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you don't want to execute a shell command you can (as you mentioned) use the settimeofday,  i would start by reading the [MAN page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/settimeofday/), or looking for some examples

here's an example:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct timeval now;
    int rc;

    now.tv_sec=866208142;
    now.tv_usec=290944;

    rc=settimeofday(&now, NULL);
    if(rc==0) {
        printf("settimeofday() successful.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("settimeofday() failed, "
        "errno = %d\n",errno);
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Shamelessly ripped From [IBMs documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/apis/settod.htm),  the `struct timeval` struct holds the number of seconds (as a `long`) plus the number of microseconds (as a `long`) from 1 January 1970, 00:00:00 UTC (Unix Epoch time).  So you will need to calculate these numbers in order to set the time.  you can use these [helper functions](http://linux.die.net/man/3/timercmp), to better handle dealing with the timeval struct.

Comment: often these days i just use google to search man pages (unless I'm right there in the terminal),  usually the "I' Feeling Lucky" search nails it every time if you just enter man 'query'.  If you are using firefox or chrome you can just type it into the address bar.

Comment: tv_usec is actually micro seconds not milli seconds